# permission to make sounds - android studio api above 21

Tags: java, android

I am trying to activate my app in my cell
but I need permission by code
I tried them all for making sounds

---

```
android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT
android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
android.permission.BIND_VOICE_INTERACTION
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.INTERNET
```

---

all of this in my manifest and by code!
but doesn't work! - it allways crashes when its about above api 21
thank you for helping!

Comment: Visit [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: You can use my library to handle runtime permissions easily: https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Answer (score 1):

There are some permissions that have to be asked for on runtime(API >= 21), such as Storage permissions.
You can try the code below to see how it works:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

For more detailed information, please visit:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I know how- I am asking what am I missing? its still not working

Comment: @golan You probably missing all the permissions required to ask. Please add some error output from console

Comment: I writed down to martin - the all permission code I did below - and that my log :-----------java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: getPermissionFlags requires android.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS or android.permission.REVOKE_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS

Answer (score 0):

Request  your permissions like this

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                1);
```

Comment: yes I know how... it asks permission good - but when I try to active sounds its crashes

Comment: Post your logcat then

Comment: List<String> permList=new ArrayList<>();
        int capturAudioPerm = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT);
        int audioSettingPerm = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS);
        int audioPerm = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        int voicePerm = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.BIND_VOICE_INTERACTION);
        int readPerm = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

Comment: The logcat is the android monitor, that shows why it is crashing

Comment: if (readPerm != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            permList.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }

Comment: else
        {
            audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            storageManager = (StorageManager)context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
        }

Comment: logcat: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: getPermissionFlags requires android.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS or android.permission.REVOKE_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS